# Why are GBK encoded files identical when compared to UTF-8 text

Tags: java, character-encoding, character

I use InputStreamReader to read the GBK encoding txt, I thought lineTxt would be GBK encoded as well, but when I compare to the "WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N" which is enconding by UTF-8, they are the same.

here is the code:

1、s is the String of UTF-8 encoding

2、lineTxt is the String of GBK encoding(I'm not sure, but i know the "read" is GBK)

3、I guess the "lineTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()" trigger a transform if encoding, not sure.

```
try (InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), ENCODING_GBK);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(read)) {
        String lineTxt;
        while ((lineTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineTxt.contains("WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N")) {
                String s = new String("输出坐标系：WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes()));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineTxt.getBytes()));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Read file failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the file. ASCII characters are encoded in the same manner on UTF-8 and GBK, so files with just ASCII characters will be identical. If you add some non ASCII characters you will see differences: they have two different ways to encode characters

Comment: Calling `getBytes()` without specifying the character set, will use the platform default, which is likely `UTF-8` (unless you're on Windows and use a Java version before Java 18). So in all cases, you're producing byte-arrays with UTF-8 bytes. Strings inside Java don't really have a notion of a character set (though on some levels, you can think of them as UTF-16), only when converting from or to bytes do a character set come into play.

Comment: the "输出坐标系：WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N" is not a ASCII characters，but when the byte array of it compare to lineTxt.getBytes() which is same as  "输出坐标系：WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N" , they are same. you can try this code.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file and store the lines as a String object, the encoding is converted to the internal representation of String (UTF-16). `lineTxt.getBytes()` converts the UTF-16 String to a byte array in your platform's default encoding (It's depends on the system locale when you're on Windows. It would be UTF-8 when you're on the other platform).

If you want to get the content of the file to a byte array (get the GBK representation and don't want to convert the content to UTF-16), read the file like this:

```java
try {
    File file = new File("C:\\tmp\\fileGBK.txt");
    byte[] lineTxt = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineTxt));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will get the representation of the string in GBK (`[-54, -28, -77, -10, -41, ...`).

If you want to read lines from the file one by one and get the GBK representation of the lines:

```java
File file = new File("C:\\tmp\\fileGBK.txt");
final Charset ENCODING_GBK = Charset.forName("GBK");
try (InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), ENCODING_GBK);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(read)) {
    String lineTxt;
    while ((lineTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (lineTxt.contains("WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N")) {
            String s = new String("输出坐标系：WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes()));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineTxt.getBytes(ENCODING_GBK)));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```